# Is it possible to simplify $\int \phi^{-1}(c + \phi(x))dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Suppose that $\Phi'= \phi$. Is it possible to calculate 
$$
\int \phi^{-1}(c + \phi(x))\,dx
$$
directly in terms of $\Phi$ (and possibly $\Phi^{-1}, \phi, \phi^{-1}$ and so on)?

At first I tried per partes, since the substitution of $t = c + \phi(x)$ is impossible at this time.
$$
    \int \phi^{-1}(c + \phi(x))\,dx = 
    x \phi^{-1}(c + \phi(x)) - \int \frac{x \phi'(x)}{\phi'(\phi^{-1}(c+\phi(x)))}\,dx
$$
This doesn't help much.

So I tried to see some special cases to see if a pattern emerges:
$$\begin{align}
\int e^{c+ \log(x)}\,dx &= e^c \frac{x^2}{2} + K\\
\int \log(c+ e^x)\,dx &= Li_2\left(-\frac{e^x}{c}\right) + x [\log(c + e^x) - \log(c)] + K \\
\int (c + \sqrt{x})^2\,dx &= c^2x + \frac{4}{3}cx^{\frac{3}{2}} + \frac{x^2}{2} + K
\end{align}$$

But again, nothing obvious.

Is this a futile quest, or is it worth pursuing more?

Comment: $\int (c+ W(x))e^{c + W(x)} = \frac{e^{c+2W(x)}}{4}(c + 2c W(x) + 2 W(x)^2) + K$, for Lambert-W function